# Can't find where to edit content

Tags: 8, nodes, emails

I've recently inherited an Drupal 8 website.  www.berkslibraries.org  At the bottom of the site in the footer there is the word Contact and under it a link to Hours & Locations, email address, and a phone number.  I have searched through Drupal and can't find where that information in stored to change it.  It's not in the content section or in the custom blocks.  I was hoping someone might have some advice on where I can possibly look to change that info.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Judging from the lack of block or menu HTML wrappers around this section, it looks like this is embedded in the site's page template.  You will not be able to edit this from the GUI.  Instead, look in the theme directory, templates subdirectory for the files that need to be edited.

Comment: Thanks, yes I think it is somehow embedded into the website.  So you think I need I need shell level access to actually make the change?

Comment: Depends on your setup.  If the webserver is linked to a repository like GIT, then you will need access to that repository and info on how to push changes.  E.g. clone the repository locally, find the template file that needs to be changed, change and push /deploy to the site.  Alternatively, you could do the same thing with FTP, SFTP, or SCP access to the site files.  (Copy the site files down instead of clone).

Answer (score 0):

When you log in as admin. just hover your cursor over the words and you can do a quick edit. You might have tried create content. If you just click content, all content created will populate.

Comment: Thanks but that doesn't work.  This content seems to be embedded somehow into the page.  It's not one of your regular piece of contents like an article or basic page that you can edit.  It is not a custom block either.  I have a column 3 custom block that will add content right below the phone number if I enter data.